# SpringBoot, Thymeleaf. th:ech вывод одинаковых записей один раз

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

```
 <form method="post"  th:action="staffFilter">
                <input class="inn" type="hidden" name="filter" placeholder="Поиск по должности" id="position" />
                <select class="inn" onchange=document.getElementById('position').value=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value>
                    <option disabled selected >Должность</option>
                    
                    <option th:each="staff : ${staffs}"
                            th:value="${staff.position}"
                            th:text="${staff.position}">
                    </option>
                </select>
                <div class="DivRequest1" >
                    <button class="btnComment" type="submit">Найти</button>
                </div>
            </form>
```

У меня имеется таблица staff, где администратор добавляет сотрудников ФИО, должность. Админ может воспользоваться поиском (фильтр) поиск по должности. При добавлении новых сотрудников у них может быть одна должность (электромонтер, слесарь и тд), и в выпадающем списке фильтра эти должности показываются. Но если есть два электромонтера, то в выпадающем списке тоже будет два электромонтера. Как заставить thymeleaf выводить записи без повторений?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

```
@Controller
public class AdminController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;
    @Autowired
    private StaffRepository staffRepository;

    /* Выводим таблицу сотрудников */

    @GetMapping("/admin")
    public String admin(Model model) {
        Iterable<Staff> staffs = staffRepository.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("staffs", staffs);
        model.addAttribute("title", "Администратор");
        return "adminHTML/admin";
    }

    /* Добавить нового сотрудника */

    @PostMapping("/admin")
    public String allStaff(@RequestParam String fname,
                           @RequestParam String lname,
                           @RequestParam String pname,
                           @RequestParam String position,
                           Model model) {
        Staff post = new Staff(fname, lname, pname, position);
        staffRepository.save(post);
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }

    /* Значения из БД занесены в форму редактирования */

    @GetMapping("/admin/{id}/edit")
    public String staffEdit(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) {
        if (!staffRepository.existsById(id)) {
            return "redirect:/admin";
        }
        Optional<Staff> post = staffRepository.findById(id);
        ArrayList<Staff> res = new ArrayList<>();
        post.ifPresent(res::add);
        model.addAttribute("post", res);
        return "adminHTML/staffEdit";
    }

    /*Редактирование сотрудника*/

    @PostMapping("/admin/{id}/edit")
    public String staffUpdate(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id,
                              @RequestParam String fname,
                              @RequestParam String lname,
                              @RequestParam String pname,
                              @RequestParam String position,
                              Model model) throws Exception {
        Staff post = staffRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(Exception::new);
        post.setFname(fname);
        post.setLname(lname);
        post.setPname(pname);
        post.setPosition(position);
        staffRepository.save(post);
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }

    /* Удалить сотрудника */

    @PostMapping("/admin/{id}/remove")
    public String staffDelete(@PathVariable(value = "id") long id, Model model) throws Exception {
        Staff post = staffRepository.findById(id).orElseThrow(Exception::new);
        staffRepository.delete(post);
        return "redirect:/admin";
    }

    /* Фильтр для поиска сотрудников по должности */

    @PostMapping("staffFilter")
    public String staffFilter(@RequestParam String filter, Model model) {
        Iterable<Staff> staffs;
        if (filter != null && !filter.isEmpty()) {
            staffs = staffRepository.findDistinctByPosition(filter);
        } else {
            staffs = staffRepository.findAll();
        }
        model.addAttribute("staffs", staffs);
        return "adminHTML/admin";
    }

}
```

---

```
    public interface StaffRepository extends JpaRepository<Staff, Long> {
    
        //    Вывод всей таблицы сотрудников
        List<Staff> findAll();
    
        //    ФИЛЬТРЫ
        List<Staff> findByPosition(String position);
    
        List<Staff> findDistinctByPosition(String position);

}
```

Answer (score 1):

В вашем контроллере добавте новый атрибут `positions`. Переменную получите из вашего объекта `staffs` используя `.distinct()` или `Collectors.toSet()`  ...

```
Iterable<Staff> staffs = staffRepository.findAll();
Set<String> positions = staffs.stream().map(Staff::getPosition).collect(Collectors.toSet());
model.addAttribute("positions", positions);
```

В HTML коде используйте его для элемента селект ...

```
<option th:each="position : ${positions}"
                        th:value="${position}"
                        th:text="${position}">
                </option>
```

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий, но к сожалению не работает. Помучал я Ваш код и ни к чему не пришел.
Также пробовал 
 List<Staff> findDistinctByPosition (String position);
 List<Staff> findDistinctByPositio(List<String> position); 
@Query("SELECT DISTINCT position FROM Staff")    
List<Staff> findDistinctByPosition();

Comment: Не заметил что вы добавили код, я перепишу ответ.